# Removing System.ServiceModel.TransactionFlowAttribute

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to convert a project written in .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net 6. Everything's fine but there are couple of auto-generated WCF services for some SOAP APIs on the "Connected Services" directory in "References.vb" files that contain a line:
`System.ServiceModel.TransactionFlowAttribute(System.ServiceModel.TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)`

It basically adds this attribute to some of the functions. I searched and it seems like there's no alternative for this attribute on .Net 6. If that's the case, would removing this attribute cause any issues or the project would work as expected?

Comment: Are there any specific error messages for this project? You can check if [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5#windows-communication-foundation) helps.

Comment: @LanHuang Thanks for the reply. Actually the reason that I asked, is that it seems to be working but I'm not sure if I'm missing something. I don't want to push it to production and somewhere along the way see it fail for something that I have missed now.